# How to generate a stream of sinusoidal waveforms seperated by zeros?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

```
% initialize pulse width
t0 = 0;
t1 = 10;
t = t0: 0.01: t1;
% initialize number of pulses
nPulse = 4;
x = sin(t);
figure (1);
plot(t, x);
axis tight;
% initialize PRI (pulse repetition interval)
PRI = 20;
delay = zeros(1, PRI);
inputsignal = [x delay];
figure (2);
plot(inputsignal)
for i = 3: 5
    inputsignal(:, i) = inputsignal(:, i - 2);
    if i <= 4
        for i = i + 1
            inputsignal(:, i) = inputsignal(:, i - 2);
        end
    end
end
figure (3)
plot(inputsignal(:, i))
```

Basically, I want to generate a train of sinusoids separated by zeros. Specifically, I would like to generate four pulses; each pulse is followed by a vector of zeros. I was hoping to get something along the lines of inputsignal = [x delay x delay x delay x delay].

The PRI parameter defines the zeros that should follow each pulse.

Answer (score 1):

You want to simply use `repmat` to repeat your series of `x` and `delay` prior to plotting.

```
% Repeat this 4 times
data = repmat([x delay], [1 4]);

% Plot the data
plot(data);
```

[image]